# Java Requests with json data

Tags: java

I want to make an HTTP request with Java,
but I'm new to Java and have no clue how.
I've had a look at a few tutorials,
but I was unable to understand anything.
I want to send JSON data and also receive JSON data.
In Python it would look like this:

```py
response = json.load(urllib.request.urlopen(urllib.request.Request('http://localhost:8765', requestJson)))
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: show us some code you tried. It's a good starting point

Comment: I haven't tried anything because I never was able to understand what was happening. I am sure I could just copy paste some code from anywhere. But I want to learn Java and not learn how to press ctrl +c and ctrl +v

Comment: @rkosegi Yes it does. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use the below link for reference
https://www.baeldung.com/java-http-request

You can use rest template also if you're using external library.

```
ResponseEntity<> response = restTemplate.exchange(
                    UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(baseurl + "jobs").toString(),
                    HttpMethod.POST,
                    new HttpEntity<>(body,headers),
                    <someClass>.class);
```

Comment: Ok and where do I put my json data?